How do i fix my html website not finding any images?
I have a "templates" folder and a "images" folder located in my project directory. Inside the templates folder I have the base.html file that is supposed to display the image located in the images folder. However, when i go on the website and open the console, it says: GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/images/address.png 404 (NOT FOUND). The image is not displayed.

main.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session, url_for
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# Routes
@app.route('/')
def index():

    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/home')
def home():

    return render_template('base.html')

@app.route('/rd')
def rd():

    return 

@app.route('/about', methods=['GET'])
def about():

    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)

I have tried changing the directory to /images/address.png, ./images/address.png and etc., non worked
I expected the image to show up

try ../images/address.png ,  ../ goes one level up from current dir, so you are at the root, and then go to folder images

I just found out it actually works when i open the file in the browser, but doesnt work when i launch my python flask application file and open the base page

put the images folder inside templates folder, for your fast recovery answer hack, however the real answer would be to use ../images/address.png instead of one .

Doesnt work, seems to be a flask issue

You need to store your images in the /static folder, and use the url_for function to retrieve them in the html code.
You can also use app.static_folder=/path to change the static folder path.
Example
source
File structure
static
  |- images
      |- daniel-shapiro--QtglPvx3I0-unsplash.jpg

templates
  |- index.html

main.py

main.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

index.html
<h3>This is an apple</h3>

<img
  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/daniel-shapiro--QtglPvx3I0-unsplash.jpg') }}"
  class="image"
/>

<style>
  .image {
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>

codesandbox

Updated answer
Put the 'images' folder into 'static' folder.
Replace 'about.html' line 6 with <img class="tinyimg" src="static/images/address.png">.
Flask serves static files via the static folder by default.

Old answer
Please post your source code in text.
You'll want to use ../images/address.png.
Explanation
../ moves up one directory level from the current location. Since your HTML is running in "PermanentEstet/templates", you'll need to move up from "templates" folder, and into "PermanentEstet/images".

Doesnt work, seems to be a flask issue

Let's see your Python code. Please edit your question to include it in code format (Ctrl + K)

added the python code as you asked
